# Reserve proxy to an LXC container

Tags: ubuntu, reverse-proxy, lxc

I'm using a virtual host on ubuntu 16.04 desktop to deploy a project from [GitHub](https://github.com/nordic-institute/X-Road). This project once built deploys containers in LXD that I can reach in my browser. The url looks like `https://container-private-ip:4000` that will **only** work with HTTPS and port 4000. This works well, after allowing an unsecured connection to the website.

Now I wish to deploy the GitHub project on a VPS. I got the reverse proxy to work in the guide but for my use-case I cant seem to figure it out. What can I do differently?

[nmap screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHMnS.png)

[Link to the reverse proxy guide I used.](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/beginners-guide-to-lxd-reverse-proxy)

The code for the `proxy` container:

```
server {

        server_name ca.domain.come;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://futura-ca.lxd:4000; # container name

        }

        real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
        set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ca.katunka.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ca.katunka.me/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = ca.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 proxy_protocol;
        listen [::]:80 proxy_protocol;

        server_name ca.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The "ping" command in the screenshot has a typo. You added at the end a port number but in the case of "ping", it has been interpreted as a IP address. Yes, an IP and a number are treated the same.

Comment: I did not know that! I googled and used nmap in the link now, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Within containers, you can use domains names like `proxy.lxd` and `futura-ca.lxd`. The website on `futura-ca.lxd` can be a plain Website on port 80 and there is no HTTPS on that specific website. The reason is that the proxy container acts as a *TLS Termination Proxy*, which means that HTTPS is handled from the visitor's browser up to (and including) the proxy server in the container.

If port 4000 is the default port of a specific Web application, then you can still use that port. But if not, then it is simpler to stick to port 80.

You run `certbot` from withing the TLS termination proxy (the `proxy` container), and it takes care of obtaining for you a Let's Encrypt certificate. And installing it.

Comment: so certbot is working as should. Whenever I go to ca.domain.com it redirects to https, but from what I understand from your comment HTTPS wont be able to reach the LXD container futura-ca? And if so how should I go about this? I'm very new to reverse proxies and LXD so any code would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to try the Linode tutorial again on a new VPS. You need to configure the hostnames as needed. The `proxy` container is where the TLS (SSL, aka HTTPS) connection terminates and the further connection to the website container is a plain HTTP connection. That is how a TLS Termination Proxy works.

Comment: I'm currently reading about TLS termination. However, I only changed the ca.domain.name with HTTPS. The apache.domain.com and nginx.domain.com are both working using  HTTP. If HTTPS works like that I'm sure I can use the subdomain without HTTPS, but however I would need to proxy_pass to a container that has a website on HTTPS, which due to lack my lack of knowledge in this field is getting harder to google on :(